# Retrieve problems for each assignment of planning variable

Tags: optimization, optaplanner, timefold

I'm working on a school scheduling application based on OptaPlanner that displays problems interactively during drag and drop:

[image]

I have naively implemented this by looping over every valid timeslot, assigning it to the lecture then retrieving the constraint matches for the resulting schedule using `solutionManager.explain(schedule).getConstraintMatchTotalMap()`. (I collect the errors in a map from timeslot to list of problems and return to front end.)

### The problem

My problem is that with a couple of hundred lectures and 5-minute intervals (~500 timeslots), this becomes very slow. It takes about 5 seconds before the problems are fully computed for all positions.

I notice that during the CH phase, valid slots are computed insanely fast. I don't know a lot about OptaPlanner internals, but I suspect it's because it does incremental changes to the schedule, instead of starting all over for every lecture / timeslot assignment.

### My question

Is there any way I can speed up this errors-by-timeslot scanning procedure?

### My thoughts so far

If there's no first class support for this use case, I'm open to unholy hacks. I'm thinking of creating a custom solver, with a move list factory that feeds OptaPlanner with timeslot assigments for the dragged lecture, just to make the computation incremental. Is there a better way?!

**After further research:** Would it be possible to solve this using a custom phase? I.e. by calling `changeWorkingSolution` for each timeslot update? If so, how would I retrieve the current score explanation? Would I have to fiddle with `SolutionUpdatePolicy`?

Comment: I bet our upcoming [recommendation/ranking API](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/issues/123) might solve all your problems, better.

Comment: Fantastic. Subscribed to the issue. Looking forward to it. I don't want to go into a 5 page babbling here, but what I'm currently struggling with in my school scheduling application is that it's almost impossible to get out of a local optima. Lessons given in half-classes (like labs and such) _have_ to be matched against "counter"-half-class lessons. Example: Chemistry labs with `SCI2022:a` _must_ be read at the same time as for example Physics labs with `SCI2022:b` (where `:a` and `:b` are half-class). Otherwise...

Comment: ...there's simply no viable schedule. `SCI2022:b` can't have a gap while `SCI2022:a` is doing their labs. If the schedule is in a state where all physics teachers are busy when `SCI2022:a` has a chemistry lab, the solver can't seem to figure out how to swap lectures so that the labs are "matched up". This is obviously completely off topic for this question, but since you're so responsive and seem to listen to your users, I'm curious if you'd be interested in a short write-up regarding my experience with OptaPlanner/Timefold regarding school schedule generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not sure I understand the problem well enough. The following call indeed does not use incremental calculation, and therefore will be slow:

```
solutionManager.explain(schedule).getConstraintMatchTotalMap()
```

Hooking into `ScoreDirector` instead of `SolutionManager` could possibly get you closer to the bits that do incremental score calculation. (And outside the realm of public API.) That said, constraint justifications were never really optimized for performance; that feature is not designed to provide real-time information.

The use case (as much as I understand it) does make sense though. We may yet do something about this in [Timefold](https://timefold.ai/).

Comment: Wow, first time I hear about Timefold. Definitely need to read up on that project. So I don't know if I can summarize/clarify my use case in a comment, but basically I'd like to answer the question _"What constraint matches do we have for schedule `X`?"_ where `X` is [current schedule but with the start timeslot of lecture `Y` set to `Z`] for every possible value of `Z`. (I then filter out the problems relevant for lecture `Y` and display it to the user.) Did you read my last "after further research" that I added just a few minutes before your answer? Do you have any comments on that?

Comment: What I'm currently thinking is that this should be doable via Score Director, instead of Solution Manager. You can send variable updates to it, and it will process them incrementally. You can then read the new justifications. It will be slow, because justifications are slow - but it will be as fast as currently possible, because it will be incremental. Just FYI the score director implementations you'll need for this are definitely not stable public API.

Comment: Ok, this is what I've got at the moment: https://pastebin.com/PrXTT8Nq Am I on the right track? Can you confirm that this should achieve incremental score calculation? FWIW, the calculation time is cut in half in my case, so quite an improvement.

Comment: You only change a single variable, and you calculate the score without resetting solution. Yes, this should do incremental score calculation. If you're hunting peak performance, I think that the rest of the code (unrelated to OP/Timefold) could use some tweaking too, but that's not in scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks Lukáš! Invaluable help as usual.